# setfacl for all users

Tags: access-control-list, setfacl

Is it possible to set the permission for all users or all groups that are present in the acl?

Namely, I would like a command that applies permissions uniformly for all members of an entity type, including the owning entities:

Ie:

```
setfacl g:*:perms
setfacl u:*:perms
```

Where the above modifies the perms of the owning entities as well (ie calls chmod)

Answer (score 1):

`chmod a+$perms` is enough there, setting an acl for everyone really makes no sense...

Comment: Isn't here a difference?: `a` is for **all**, while the ACLs are *not everybody*, but every user *listed*.